# Can SAN/NAS storage attach to cloud server?

Tags: mysql, storage, nas, san

Currently my boss ask my team to relocate our database to cloud server(Windows). Beside that, he also asked us to attach SAN/NAS storage to that server for a better speed/performance. The problem is we have no experiences in SAN/NAS storage.

The question is, can SAN/NAS storage be attach to cloud server? If can, is this a good practice? We currently using MySQL for our database.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

are we talking about a private or public cloud (AWS, Azure) ? though there are storage arrays that are able to proxy cloud storage, I don't think there are product to attach onsite storage array to a server in public cloud.

The reason why you want to use ie SAN is for performance - minimum latency. Imagine the connection between a storage array in a separate datacenter to a cloud server over TCP/IP, possibly far appart. The latency would make it unusable for ie. high transaction workload and defeat the purpose of a storage array.

If you were talking about a private cloud - VMware orchestrated or Openstack, then that might be possible via RDM (VMware) or Cinder (probably Cinder storage node). I think Azure is adding a feature where you can integrate part of the local infrastructure to Azure as an availability zone, so there might be possibilities.